# printf and getenv

Tags: c

Ubuntu 10.04, C, gcc, x86 Intel proc:

When trying to print the address of an environmental variable using printf, the address printed is not correct in this toy program (this is a consciously backward version in which I tried to isolate the source of the problem by saving the address value on the heap, not using a pointer directly as I read it can be overwritten, and using a pointer straight up produced the same issue):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(){

    const char* d = getenv("TEST");
    unsigned i = (unsigned*) malloc(sizeof(unsigned));
    i = (unsigned*) d;

    printf("%s at location 0x%8d.\n", "TEST", i);

}
```

---

EDIT: same issue with this (the original) version)

```
int main(){

    const char* d = getenv("TEST");
    printf("%s at location %p.\n", "TEST", d);

    return 0;
}
```

### *This question has nothing to do with how to print a pointer. Kindly read on.*

If I change the program to not print TEST's address, but TEST as a string (its value), no problem.

However, the address returned is not the address at which the environmental variable is actually located before entering the print sub-routine; and which, by the above set-up, should be printed. Using main's disassembly and TEST's address in the eax register, I am referred to the proper location of the TEST variable, which is a little further down than main's stack frame at about 0xbffffiii on my system (i any hex value). The address value printed is on the order of 0xbfeiiiii.

I don't understand. Is this a security precaution to prevent environmental variables from being overwritten (eg, to smash the stack)? If yes, does the compiler really keep track of transferring the address as I do above, and silently adjusting its value?

Or am I missing something? (probably)

Many thanks.

P.S.: To remove imaginable sources of issues, I compiled first with no options, then:
gcc -O0 -static -fno-stack-protector -g program.c

Comment: What do you use `malloc` in this case for? Is this 32 bit or 64bit? You should use `ptrdiff_t` to store pointer values, because in 64 bit, for example, `unsigned` is not enough to store the addresses.

Comment: I should have posted my original version which printed using %p obviously. My issues is entirely different.

Comment: You should be getting all sorts of compiler warnings about assigning a pointer to an integer for the line declaring and initializing `i`.  Heed the warnings of your compiler!

Comment: This is a horribly written question.

Comment: I think you're just being confused by the fact that running programs under gdb turns off ASLR (address space layout randomization).

Comment: R.: That is very possibly it. I am not familiar with the concept (learning now) and will read up on it. Many thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured it out, following a comment by R.. further above who pointed me in the direction of ASLR.

I was unfamiliar with ASLR stack protection. What I describe is due to ASLR scrambling the memory address space to prevent prediction of the location of variables relative to it. ASLR has long been default switched on in LINUX kernels it appears.

To see what I meant, get su privileges, then enter (the precise integer to send might vary based on your distro; on mine it is 0, and the default 2. Also better confirm the file only contains 1 integer by first looking at it, as it does on my system):

```
cd /proc/sys/kernel
export OLD=$(less randomize_va_space) // save old value to restore after
echo 0 >  randomize_va_space  // 0 == turn off ASLR
```

Then run my little program again: it will report back the address I expected (around 0xbffffiii). After, obviously, restore old protection using

```
echo $OLD > randomize_va_space
```

Many thanks for everyone who spend some of their time trying to help.

Answer (score 3):

This is not the right way to print an address. Just use the `%p` format to print `(void*)d`.

```
printf("%s at location 0x%p.\n", "TEST", (void*)d);
```

Comment: Well I know that.That's obviously how my first version of the program looked like. Kindly have a look at what I write: the address returned is simply not the address at which the string is located during program execution, as i confirm going through the disassembly. The only reason for the backward way of printing this was to make sure it was not related to (1) the pointer being overwritten before printed, and (2) making the pointer a different pointer in a simplistic attempt to check if my problem was related to an inherent smash protection feature. have a look at what my problem really is.

Comment: well and technically, your fmt string will print 0x0x. :) using %p, no need to add 0x too (at least not on my system).

Comment: What do you expect to be returned? The address of "TEST" in your program plus a few bytes? How do you know where the **environment** string is located during program execution? IOW, what did you expect?

Comment: see also below (1) Yes. I expect location of program main stack frame plus some bytes (on the order of 0x200-0x300 I believe on my system) (2) during program execution, i go to the disassembly. the location returned (into eax on my system) holds the TEST string, and is where expected in (1) (3) printf returns a location before (lower memory address) the main stack frame

Comment: @gnometorule: The output produced for `%p` is implementation-defined; on some systems, it doesn't include a leading `0x`.  (In my own debugging code, I often use `"[%p]"` so pointer values are visually distinct.)

Answer (score 0):

Storing a `char*` pointer in an `unsigned` variable might work on some systems, but is not portable. For example, on my 64-bit Ubuntu box `sizeof(char*)==8` and `sizeof(unsigned)==4`. The portable way to store a pointer in an integer variable is to use the `intptr_t` type.

Alternatively, to simply print the address use `%p` like so:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main() {
    const char* d = getenv("TEST");
    printf("%s at location %p.\n", "TEST", d);
}
```

On my Ubuntu box, this prints out either

```
TEST at location (nil).
```

or

```
TEST at location 0x7fff8cf34628.
```

depending on whether `$TEST` is set (of couse the address can vary).

Comment: Thanks much - have a look at my comment to the first answer please. Define a shell variable yourself as in the usual export TEST=(...), then run your prog and keep track of the location of TEST in the disassembly. The location reported back (as I write above) is simply not the location during program execution which should be printed - at least not in my system; with address differences on my system referred to above.

Comment: @gnometorule: you do know that the environment variables get copied to the environment of a program that is started, so each program has its own **copy**?

Comment: Could you pls elaborate? I was thinking along these lines. Wouldn't my hacky version of saving the old pointer on the heap preserve the value from when we were in main? That was the only reason for the ugly code. Note also I compiled using static linkage. I am working through understanding security; and this is similar to a famous book in which (per Ubuntu 6.10) the program should report back as I expected, and describe above.

Comment: And yes, Rudy: that is the core of my issue (if I understand you correctly). The environmental variables are ~ x200-300 higher (as in at higher memory addresses) than main's stack frame, which - on my system - would be in the 0xbffffiii range, and I see them there during disassembly (on my system, getenv feeds eax with the proper address). But the print is 0xbfeiiiii, which is lower than the stack. But kindly elaborate if you have further ideas.

Answer (score 0):

> However, the address returned is not the address at which the
>   environmental variable is actually located before entering the print
>   sub-routine; and which, by the above set-up, should be printed. Using
>   main's disassembly and TEST's address in the eax register, I am
>   referred to the proper location of the TEST variable, which is a
>   little further down than main's stack frame at about 0xbffffiii on my
>   system (i any hex value). The address value printed is on the order of
>   0xbfeiiiii.

Note that there are several copies being made here: the literal `"TEST"` in your program, used to find the key `"TEST"` in the environment of your program, the value string for the key `"TEST"` in that environment and a pointer to that value string returned by `getenv()`. I don't know what you expected to get, but the environment is generally not near the stack in any of the x86 environments I know.

What you probably saw in the disassembly was the pointer to the `"TEST"` string in your program, somewhere in the local stackframe for `main()`. That is **not** the environment variable, that is a string used to **search for** the environment variable in the environment, by comparing the string in your program with the real one.

So I don't really know what you expected, but it looks as if you are expecting the wrong thing, sorry.

The address of the literal `"TEST"` should be somewhere in your program, probably in a read-only segment. The address of the pointer to that string is somewhere close to the stack pointer. The address of the string `"TEST"` in your environment should not be near the stack at all (probably at a lower address than your program). The string associated with `"TEST"` should be very near to it, and that should be the address returned by `getenv()`.

Comment: I see your point, but that's not the case. My original post was poorly formulated. To just stick to my system, the environmental variables are located at around 0xbffffiii, with a main stack frame located around 0xbffffiii too, but at addresses lower by about -0x200-0x300. Here is what I did: (1) gdb, print out memory region around the above. I find the regular env variables, and the one I defined, (2) I disassemble. after a system call to getenv, eax holds the address I confirmed in (1), (3) print prints a lower address than even $esp, however, is handed the proper value before system call.

Comment: Note also that I originally submitted the hacky malloc version to perma store the address I get back from the getenv call, to avoid confusions about different pointers.

Comment: I don't know what happens there, but if you `printf("%p --> %s\n", d, d);`, what do you see?

Comment: Good idea (...that I should have long checked...): it points to TEST, and prints the string I have in it. So it's the location after the program terminates. ---- But why would it be that location is still my question, and not the one from when the program ran, and when we got the pointer? My guess is it's some form of smash protection. Any ideas?

Comment: To avoid this (returning the address after program termination) from happening, I had also tested the program by adding token lines after that to just wait for input, and it still printed the same address as described above.

Comment: What do you mean "the location after the program terminates"? It can only print something when the program did not terminate yet.

Comment: Just strike what I said. You are right on this point.

Answer (score 0):

You are assuming that environment variables are stored in some particular place, apparently based on examining memory with gdb.  I suggest that it's not your program's output that's incorrect, but your assumptions about where environment variables are stored.

`getenv()` returns a pointer to a string which hold the value of the specified environment variable.  If it's at a different address than what you expected, how is that a problem?

Consider the following program:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(void) {
    const char *test = getenv("TEST");
    if (test == NULL) {
        puts("test == NULL");
    }
    else {
        printf("test == %p, points to \"%s\"\n", (void*)test, test);
        /* WARNING: The following has undefined behavior! */
        *(char*)test = 'X';
        system("echo $TEST");
    }
    return 0;
}
```

When I run it on my system (Ubuntu 11.04, x86, gcc 4.3.4) with `$TEST` set to "foobar", it prints:

```
test == 0x6125f299, points to "foobar"
Xoobar
```

So `getenv()` gave me a pointer to a string that, when I modified it, showed up as a change in the environment of a child process.

Again, what exactly is the problem?

Comment: Thanks for taken the time to discuss this. The problem for me is mostly academic. As you point out, if the goal is to print what getenv reports back, we are fine, no matter the source/address of the string. However, you don't find what i describe curious? I save the address which is near the main stack frame, try to print it - and it's adjusted, while still pointing to the string requested, no feedback provided? What if you need *this* address (not a pointer to the string) - for whatever purpose? (to keep THIS address, I originally submitted the ugly hacky version).

Comment: @gnometorule: I don't understand the significance of this "address which is near the main stack frame".  What leads you to think that it's the "right" address?  For what purpose is it better?

Comment: I never said 'better.' I said, I am - mostly academically - interested in what is happening here, and why. It appears that all env variables are parked at addresses a little higher than the main stack frame, and I confirm that. Why the change?

Comment: @gnometorule: Sorry, I still don't understand what "change" you're talking about.  You found copies of environment variables "at addresses a little higher than the main stack frame".  What is the significance of those copies?  In your original question, you said the address printed is "not correct"; what exactly is not correct about it?

Comment: Here is one way of how I tested this: (1) get address (which then points to near stack frame) into a pointer p, (2) copy the pointer - as an int of sufficient size - into another variable; call this second variable i (just to store it separately), (3) see in the assembly that i's value 'is' still the address near the stack frame. If you print i before even printing pointer p, its address has changed to that of the pointer. That's not a little surprising? Maybe I'm really too stupid how that is not surprising (and I mean that in no sarcastic ways). It's probably smash protection...

Comment: ...and I was hoping for color or some other explanation, or why my reasoning is, in fact, stupid.Well i seem to not be able to be precise today: after (3) above, i has changed to the value of the pointer that is different, that is far from the stack.

Comment: I did a poor job posing this question, and wasn't precise enough, in the process wasting several people's time. I'm new to stack overflow and don't want to merely delete the post, instead rather mark it 'closed' or similar. If someone can tell me how, thanks (also thanks to those who tried to help and sent helpful suggestions, Keith and Rudy in particular).

Comment: @gnometorule: One last try.  When you run your program, you see that the string "TEST" is in memory at a particular address.  You seem to think that it *should* be at some other address.  I suggest that whatever line of reasoning led you to believe that it *should* be at that other address is faulty.  Perhaps you're seeing the address of something else.  As far as I can tell, the string "TEST" that's part of the environment is at one and only one location in memory, and the revised version of your program (that doesn't try to store a pointer in an integer) prints that address correctly.